In XCode 14.2 project when I add fonts to the 'Fonts supplied by application' key, the entries disappear when I navigate away from the 'Info' tab?
I have tried to add multiple fonts (ttf and otf) to 'Fonts provided by application' key in XCode 14.2. As soon as I navigate away from the 'Info' tab the 'Fonts provided by application' key disappears. Also, the fonts never show up in the console list. I have added them to the OS (Monterey) and the XCode 14.2 project. I have repeatedly followed the instructions and been sure to follow the instructions to the letter. All fonts have been spelled correctly and the file extensions used where and when needed in the project. I am lost to understand this. Why would the 'Fonts provided by application' key disappear? The fonts are available in Font Book.
I have followed numerous suggested processes to add custom fonts to an XCode project. The instructions without exception are clear and straightforward. I have verified the steps and am sure that all instructions including the correct spelling of the fonts and use of the file extensions are used when and where required.
